# Magento upgrade CLI problem

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, composer, cli

I want to upgrade to Magento 2.1.9.
Entered command:

```
composer require magento/product-commu**m**ity-edition 2.1.9 --no-update
```

After command "composer update" I've got error message:

*Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-commumity-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.*

Found the typo and changed the command to "..commu**n**ity-edition.."
But still get the same error message (showing "commu**m**ity"). There is no typo anymore. Checked it several times.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried composer clear-cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. In composer.json there was following code:

"require": {

```
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.9",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/product-commumity-edition": "2.1.9"
},
```

I cancelled the last line and finally it worked.